# Error while executing the script in Cucumber TypeScript

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, cucumber

I'm getting below error while executing the test Cases.

```
  You're calling functions (e.g. "setDefaultTimeout") on an instance of Cucumber that isn't running.
          This means you have an invalid installation, mostly likely due to:
          - Cucumber being installed globally
          - A project structure where your support code is depending on a different instance of Cucumber
          Either way, you'll need to address this in order for Cucumber to work.
          See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/installation.md#invalid-installations
```

When i executed the below command

`npm why @cucumber/cucumber`

Below message is getting

```
@cucumber/cucumber@9.1.0
node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber
  @cucumber/cucumber@"^9.1.0" from the root project
  peer @cucumber/cucumber@">=7.0.0" from @cucumber/pretty-formatter@1.0.0
  node_modules/@cucumber/pretty-formatter
    dev @cucumber/pretty-formatter@"^1.0.0" from the root project
```

Anyone has idea how to resolve this issue?